# Does Azure App Service Custom domain allow dot '.' in the domain address?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-custom-domain

I would like to create a custom domain for my Azure App Service. Domain address I would like to use is in the format
`xx.yyyy.zzzz.com` but, it seems like Azure Custom domain doesn't allow dots '.' in the text.
Are there any restrictions related to the naming custom domain? if so where can I find that documentation?

Does anyone know how to address this?

Answer (score 0):

At your dns provider do you have a dns record for that subdomain, pointing to App Service (`<app_name>.azurewebsites.net`)?

I have setup custom domains for `zzzz.com` and `www.zzzz.com`. If I try to add custom domain for `test.blog.zzzz.com` Azure will do a lookup if correct CNAME record exists at my DNS provider!